# Как по клику кнопки чередовать показ блоков c помощью js

Tags: javascript, css

Добрый день, решил на сайте сделать показ блоков по клику на кнопки. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии сначала на кнопку 1 блок1 показывался, а по нажатию на кнопку 2 блок1 удалялся и показывался блок2. Вместо отображения двух блоков одновременно, показывался только один из них. Не судите строго, я только осваиваю js. Спасибо

```
<button class="btn" onclick="openbox('show-1'); return false">1</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="openbox('show-2'); return false">2</button>

<div id="show-1" style="display: none;">блок1</div>
<div id="show-2" style="display: none;">блок2</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function openbox(id){
            display = document.getElementById(id).style.display;
            if(display=='none'){
                document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';
            }else{
                document.getElementById(id).style.display='none';
            }
        }
</script>
```

Получилось таким образом:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('show-1').style.display =  'block'; document.getElementById('show-2').style.display =  'none';">1</button>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('show-2').style.display =  'block'; document.getElementById('show-1').style.display =  'none';">2</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас элементарно не производится никаких операций со вторым блоком. Самым простым в вашем случае решением будет в обоих onclick вызывать `openbox('show-1')` и `openbox('show-2')` (либо проделать то же самое в самой `openbox()`).

P.S. Будет работать при условии, что изначально один блок скрыт, а другой показан.